# pyQT5 Crashes when changing a variable

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am very new to pyQT5 and running into some basic issues. I am trying to increment a variable by 1 (a) and then print the answer to the terminal whenever I press the cancel button, but this causes it to crash. I am unsure of what is going on. Thanks if you can help, sorry if this seems very basic to some, still learning.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import datetime

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
  a=0
  def on_click(self):
    print("ButtonPressed")
  def func_accept(self):
    print("Displaying Time")
    current_time = str(datetime.datetime.now().time())
    ui.label1.setText(current_time)
  def func_canceled(self):
    print("Cancel")
    ui.label1.setText("Canceled")
    a=a+1
    print(a)

  def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.button1 = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.button1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 370, 156, 23))
    self.button1.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
    self.button1.setObjectName("button1")
    self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 250, 141, 61))
    self.label1.setObjectName("label1")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    self.button1.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
    self.button1.accepted.connect(self.func_accept)
    self.button1.rejected.connect(self.func_canceled) 
  def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.label1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Apples"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
  import sys
  app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
  MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
  ui = Ui_MainWindow()
  ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
  MainWindow.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with variable `a`, declare it  in `__init__` function and use. 
Check out the below code

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import datetime


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0

    def on_click(self):
        print("ButtonPressed")

    def func_accept(self):
        print("Displaying Time")
        current_time = str(datetime.datetime.now().time())
        ui.label1.setText(current_time)

    def func_canceled(self):
        print("Cancel")
        ui.label1.setText("Canceled")
        self.a += 1
        print(self.a)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.button1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 370, 156, 23))
        self.button1.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel | QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.button1.setObjectName("button1")
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 250, 141, 61))
        self.label1.setObjectName("label1")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        self.button1.accepted.connect(self.func_accept)
        self.button1.rejected.connect(self.func_canceled)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Apples"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```